# Function with fewer arguments and optional arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

I often write code that looks like this and am looking for a better suggestion. Basically, I usually create some general function `myfuc_general` that handles all the cases I need with parameters, usually with optional parameters. However, often I usually run 2 (possibly more) specific functions. Everything is the same except one of the arguments is different, in this case `a`. I run them so often that I actually prefer to just have two additional functions so I don't have to remember what the optional parameter needs to be.

So for `myfunct_specific1`, I am running `a=10` and for `myfunct_specific2`, `a=20`. Is there something better to do than this? This seems pretty sloppy and it has the disadvantage in the event that I need to change the `myfuct_general` call, then I have to change all the other functions.

```
def myfunc_general(constant, a=1,b=2):
    return constant+a+b

def myfunct_specific1(constant,b=2):
    a=10
    return myfunc_general(constant,a,b=2)

def myfunct_specific2(constant,b=2):
    a=20
    return myfunc_general(constant,a,b=2)

print myfunct_specific1(3) #15
print myfunct_specific2(3) #25
```

edit (addition):

iCodez thank you for suggestion. I have this particular situation and it is throwing me an error. Help? Thanks again

```
def myfunc_general(constant, constant2, a=0,b=2):
    return constant+constant2+b+a

import functools
myfunct_specific=functools.partial(myfunc_general,constant2=30)

print myfunct_specific
print myfunct_specific(3,5,b=3)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/test", line 8, in <module>
    print myfunct_specific(3,5,b=3)
TypeError: myfunc_general() got multiple values for keyword argument 'constant2'
```

Comment: Those nested calls are not valid syntax.

Comment: There isn't something wrong with this approach but it does have the advantages / disadvantages that you mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to make this a lot easier:

```
from functools import partial

def myfunc_general(constant, a=1, b=2):
    return constant+a+b

myfunct_specific1 = partial(myfunc_general, a=10)
myfunct_specific2 = partial(myfunc_general, a=20)
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>>
>>> def myfunc_general(constant, a=1, b=2):
...     return constant+a+b
...
>>> myfunct_specific1 = partial(myfunc_general, a=10)
>>> myfunct_specific2 = partial(myfunc_general, a=20)
>>>
>>> print myfunct_specific1(3)
15
>>> print myfunct_specific2(3)
25
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it on a different example, can you take a look at my edit in my question?

Comment: The purpose of `functools.partial` is to fill in arguments that should never change.  For example, `constant2` should never change for calls to `myfunct_specific`.  If you do want to change this argument, then you should be calling `myfunc_general` directly: `myfunc_general(3,5,b=3)`

Comment: Hm, I was expecting that constant would be set to 3. a=5,b=3, and constant2=30 from the partial. It seems that it is trying set constant2 equal to 5 and 3...which is not what I would expect. It seems that for any variable after the variable that I set using the partial, I need to use the keyword, which makes it awkward, any way to make this different?

Comment: No, `functools.partial` cannot do this.  Python would not know what arguments go with what parameters.  You could maybe build a class using [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) and a few other tools that mimics `partial` to do what you want, but I bet that most people would find it confusing.  The most pythonic solution in this case is to just define new functions like you were originally.